# Android can send messages to server but can't receive from it

Tags: java, android, client-server

I can receive messages on the server from the client, but I cant retrieve the replies from the server to Client. Any idea why? This is the code of the client and server.

Client Code

```
package com.example.clienttest;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Thread m_objThreadClient;
    Socket clientSocket;
    TextView serverMessage;
    EditText clientMessage;
    String sIn = "Nothing", sOut;
    DataOutputStream oos;
    DataInputStream ois;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        serverMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        clientMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);


        m_objThreadClient = new Thread( new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.55", 4000);
                    oos = new DataOutputStream (clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                    ois = new DataInputStream (clientSocket.getInputStream());


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    serverMessage.setText(e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
        m_objThreadClient.start();


    }

    public void Start(View view) {
        sOut = clientMessage.getText().toString();
          try {
              oos.writeUTF(sOut);

              ServerConn sc = new ServerConn(clientSocket);
              Thread t = new Thread(sc);
              t.start();

              serverMessage.setText("Reply: " + sc.msg + "\n");

              } catch (Exception e) {
              serverMessage.setText(e.getMessage());
              }

    }

    public void onStop(){
        try {
            oos.close();
            ois.close();
            clientSocket.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class ServerConn implements Runnable {
    private DataInputStream ois = null;
    public String msg;

    public ServerConn(Socket server) throws IOException {
         ois = new DataInputStream (server.getInputStream());
    }

    public void run() {
        try {

            while ((msg = ois.readUTF()) != null) {
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            msg = e.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Server code

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Server2 {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket server = null;  
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(4000); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not start up on: " + "4000" + "Maby server is already open? Or a portforwording messup?");
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Socket client = null;
        while(true) {
            try {
                client = server.accept();
                System.out.print("Connected ");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Accept failed.");
                System.err.println(e);
            }

            Thread t = new Thread(new ClientConn(client));
            t.start();
        }
    }
}


class ClientConn implements Runnable {
    private Socket client;
    String Recv, Send;
    DataInputStream inFromClient;
    DataOutputStream outToClient;

    ClientConn(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;
        try {

            inFromClient = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            outToClient = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while ((Recv = inFromClient.readUTF()) != null) {

                System.out.print("Msg: " + Recv + " \n");
                if( Recv.equals("Hi")){
                    Send = "Wa alaikum";
                }
                else{
                    Send = "Wat?";
                }

                outToClient.writeUTF(Send);
                outToClient.flush();
                System.out.print("Replying:" + Send + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("No input ");
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How/where is the client's Start() method called?

Comment: When i press a button

Answer (score 0):

The msg variable in ServerConn is given a value when it is read from the Server which is NOT immediately after the thread is started that runs the ServerConn object.  There needs to be some code (Handler??) that runs on the GUI thread that is called from the ServerConn class when it gets the msg. 
Add some debug code in the run() method that prints out the value of msg as it is read so you can see what values are in msg.  The print out will be viewable in LogCat

Comment: Are you implying I cant retrieve the msg variable at its correct time because its used a little "Later" in the code? 
Fyi I spam the "Start" function and still nothing changes.

Comment: The msg probably is not there when the setText() method is called. Add some println statements to see when the msg is available and when the setText() method is called?

Comment: I forgot to add...I tried the program on Emulator, and it works like a charm...I can receive and send messages